# How to deal with negative cosine value in this trigonometric display of complex number?

Tags: trigonometry

Im new so I don't know how to write equations so I'll just post a picture.

$$\frac{2i\left(-\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)\right)^5}{3\sqrt2-\sqrt6i}$$

I can't raise this value to the power of 5 until I get rid of the minus in front of cosine. Is it okay, and am I allowed to put that minus in front of the brackets so it would become $-2i$, and inside I would get something like this:

$$\frac{-2i\left(\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)-i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)\right)^5}{3\sqrt2-\sqrt6i}$$

And then after that I convert that to standard display like this:

$$\frac{-2i\left(\cos\left(-\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)+i\sin\left(-\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)\right)^5}{3\sqrt2-\sqrt6i}$$

$-2i$ is now treated like separate trigonometric display and from there I should be able to just multiply the top part and then divide. But I don't get the right result at the end so I immediately thought that something is wrong with the minus before cosine.

EDIT: (the solution i got)

[image]

Comment: Since you don’t tell us what you got, it is hard to guess what you did wrong. The steps you got are okay.

Comment: What difference does it make if you're calculating $(-a+ib)^5$ rather than $(a+ib)^5$? It's exactly the same algebra.

Comment: @saucy The formula for $(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^n$ begs to differ. That is the reason OP is messing with signs. The

Comment: $$-\frac{37\pi}{21}+2\pi=\frac{5\pi}{21}$$ and we prefer the final angle in either $(-\pi,\pi ]$ or $[0,2\pi).$

Comment: Not sure where the $5$ came from.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Go through [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) page to know how to type math (MathJax, to be specific) on the site.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews you mean the 5 in the modulus?

Comment: The modulus is $\frac2{\sqrt{24}}=\frac{\sqrt6}6.$ No $5.$

Comment: Your steps work. The error is elsewhere. Another approach to these steps is to use the trig identities: $$\cos(\pi-x)=-\cos x\\\sin(\pi-x)=\sin(x)$$ Then $$-\cos(2\pi/7)+i\sin(2\pi/7)=\cos(5\pi/7)+i\sin(5\pi/7).$$

Comment: Thank you for help